# What WSGI version should i use to build a python framework from scratch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm about to build a python framework from scratch...
so, im confused about the WSGI/Python version, (WSGI 1.0 used for python 2.x, WSGI 1.0.1 for python 3.x).
what is the best version should i start from? note that i will/may use some existing middlewares or some existing code.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, do you want to use Python 3 or Python 2? Obviously, Python 2 is around far longer, so there are (still) more libraries available.

Comment: I want to use a python version that remains alive for a long time (stable) because i want to use this framework for a long time

Comment: Both Python 2 and Python 3 will stay for a very long time. Python 2 for legacy reasons, and Python 3 because it is the current version.

Comment: @poke, "Both Python 2 and Python 3 will stay for a very long time.". Hope it can be true. It seems that even Google gets rid of Python

Comment: @Green Even if it gets less popular and ends up being used less, the language will very likely stay available for a long time. Your application might not be very modern then, but at least it can still run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSGI PEP 3333 is still for Python 2 and if you write to PEP 3333 it is still a valid PEP 333 WSGI application for Python 2.

Short answer is use Python 2 and go use a framework that hides the WSGI stuff from you. Don't go building one from scratch when you don't know anything about WSGI already as would be suggested by the need to ask this question in the first place.

Go look at Flask/Werkzeug.

Once you understand the principles around how Flask and the underlying Werkzeug work and how WSGI in general works, then graduate to try writing your own.